# Class Method Equivalent in C++

Tags: c++, objective-c, class, function, methods

Is there an equivalent to a class method in C++?
I know that in Objective-C we can declare a function in the header by `+ (void)aClassFunction;` and we can call it by `[myClass aClassFunction];` Is there a way to do this in C++?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, use `static`:

```
class MyClass {
public:
    static int classFunc() { return 45; }
};

cout << MyClass::classFunc() << endl;
```

You can see that you access them via the class name followed by the scope resolution operator, `::`, followed by the name of the function.

Comment: That is not the same. You cannot use a class that is computed at runtime like in Objective-C

Answer (score 11):

`static` methods are *close enough* (but not really equivalent) substitute of class methods of Objective C. The difference is that in C++ you cannot override static methods.

Comment: "The difference is that in C++ you cannot override static methods." important notice you pointed out ;)

Comment: So you're saying that I could make a class with a static function and make a subclass of it but not be able to change that function?

Comment: @ChaseWalden static ("class") functions are not inherited.

Comment: @ChaseWalden of course you can. But in Objective C there is a mechanism that amounts to calling class methods polymorphically. Essentially, in a static method of a base class you can invoke a static method of a subclass based on a particular subclass through which you invoked the base's static method.

Comment: @dasblinkenlight Do you think you could show some example code. I usually understand better if I see the code.

Comment: @ChaseWalden I created an example [on pastebin](http://pastebin.com/biq8McRk). Look at the line #25 for an example of virtual invocation of a class method.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, use static methods.

Declare a static method in the .h file like this:

```
static void DoSomething();
```

Implement it in the .cpp like this:

```
void SomeClass::DoSomething()
{
    /* do something */
}
```

Then call it like this:

```
SomeClass::DoSomething();
```

Comment: That is not the same. You cannot use a class that is computed at runtime like in Objective-C